# Having trouble getting code to draw kmap based on user input, and grouping them based on SOP and POS then writing them in simplified and original

Tags: algorithm, vector, boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

Can you fix this code for me?

#include

#include

#include

#include

#include

using namespace std;

// Function to print the Karnaugh Map

void printKMap(const vector<vector>& kMap, const vector& variables) {

```
int numRows = kMap.size();

int numCols = kMap[0].size();

cout << "========K Map========" << endl;

cout << "\\";

for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {

    cout << variables[j] << " ";

}

cout << "|" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {

        if (j == 0) {

            cout << i << " | ";

        }

        cout << kMap[i][j] << " ";

    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

}

// Function to simplify the groups and generate simplified expression

string simplifyGroups(const vector<vector>& groups, const vector& variables) {

```
stringstream ss;

for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {

    bool isFirstTerm = true;

    for (int j = 0; j < variables.size(); j++) {

        if (groups[i][j] != -1) {

            if (!isFirstTerm) {

                ss << " + ";

            }

            if (groups[i][j] == 0) {

                ss << variables[j] << "'";

            } else {

                ss << variables[j];

            }

            isFirstTerm = false;

        }

    }

}

return ss.str();
```

}

// Function to generate the original expression

string getOriginalExpression(const vector<vector>& groups, const vector& variables) {

```
stringstream ss;

for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {

    bool isFirstTerm = true;

    for (int j = 0; j < variables.size(); j++) {

        if (groups[i][j] != -1) {

            if (!isFirstTerm) {

                ss << " + ";

            }

            if (groups[i][j] == 0) {

                ss << variables[j] << "'";

            } else {

                ss << variables[j];

            }

            isFirstTerm = false;

        }

    }

}

return ss.str();
```

}

int main() {

```
char runAgain = 'Y';

while (runAgain == 'Y') {

    int numVariables;

    cout << "Enter the number of variables: ";

    cin >> numVariables;

    vector<string> variables(numVariables);

    cout << "Enter the variable letters: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) {

        cin >> variables[i];

    }

    int numLocations;

    cout << "Enter the number of locations of the 1 values: ";

    cin >> numLocations;

    int numRows = pow(2, numVariables);

    int numCols = numVariables;

    vector<vector<int>> kMap(numRows, vector<int>(numCols, 0));

    cout << "Enter the locations of the 1 values: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < numLocations; i++) {

        int location;

        cin >> location;

        kMap[location >> numVariables][location & ((1 << numVariables) - 1)] = 1;

    }

    printKMap(kMap, variables);

    vector<vector<int>> groups;

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {

            if (kMap[i][j] == 1) {

                vector<int> group(numCols, -1);

                group[j] = 1;

                for (int k = j + 1; k < numCols; k++) {

                    if (kMap[i][k] == 1) {

                        group[k] = 1;

                    }

                }

                groups.push_back(group);

            }

        }

    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {

        cout << "Group " << i + 1 << ": ";

        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {

            if (groups[i][j] != -1) {

                cout << pow(2, j) * groups[i][j] << " ";

            }

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    string simplifiedExpr = simplifyGroups(groups, variables);

    cout << "Simplified Expression: F(";

    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) {

        cout << variables[i];

        if (i < numVariables - 1) {

            cout << ",";

        }

    }

    cout << ") = " << simplifiedExpr << endl;

    string originalExpr = getOriginalExpression(groups, variables);

    cout << "Original Expression: F(";

    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) {

        cout << variables[i];

        if (i < numVariables - 1) {

            cout << ",";

        }

    }

    cout << ") = " << originalExpr << endl;

    cout << "Run again (Y/N): ";

    cin >> runAgain;

    runAgain = toupper(runAgain);

}

return 0;
```

}

This is what my professor wants the output to look like but I just can't get it right.

Enter the variable letters: WXYZ

Enter the location of the 1 values: 0 2 4 5 6 7 8 12

========K Map=========

\YZ|

WX \ | 00 01 11 10

-----+----------------

00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

-----+---+---+---+----

01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

-----+---+---+---+----

11 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

-----+---+---+---+----

10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

Group 1: 0 4 8 12

Simplification of group 1 -> Y'Z'

Group 2: 4 5 6 7

Simplification of group 2 -> W'X

Group 3: 0 2 4 6

Simplification of group 3 -> W'Z'

Simplified Expression: F(W,X,Y,Z) = Y'Z' + W'X + W'Z'

Original Expression: F(W,X,Y,Z) = W'X'Y'Z' + W'X'YZ' + W'XY'Z' + W'XY'Z + W'XYZ'

- W'XYZ + WX'Y'Z' + WXY'Z'

Run again (Y/N): N

I tried getting the output my professor wanted but the kmap doesn't draw right which I can't test my groupings or Simplification if the groupings cause I can't get the kmap to draw.